# Importing react-bootstrap modal crashes react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am getting the following errors when trying to import react-bootstrap Modal component into my react project:

```
ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in /vagrant/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js 15:29-72

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in /vagrant/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js 13:29-72

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInvalidARIAHook.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in /vagrant/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOMInvalidARIAHook.js 14:29-72

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/getNextDebugID' in /vagrant/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js 20:21-56

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDebugTool.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in /vagrant/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDebugTool.js 16:29-72

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in /vagrant/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js 29:27-70 37:31-74

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in /vagrant/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/flattenChildren.js 26:27-70 42:33-76

ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/checkReactTypeSpec.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactComponentTreeHook' in /vagrant/node_modules/react-dom/lib
 @ ./~/react-dom/lib/checkReactTypeSpec.js 29:27-70 71:37-80
```

When I remove the line where I am importing the Modal from react-bootstrap everything works just fine.

My react versions in package.json are the following:

"react": "^0.13.3",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",

Comment: Can you update react-version to `15.5.4` too.Also get the latest react-bootstrap version

Comment: Updating helped but now I am getting errors because of the old react syntax, which is preferable to use in the project. Anyway my initial problem got solved.

Comment: React v15.5.4 onwards, some new changes were introduces, that result in React.createClass, PropTypes from React being deprecated and hence you should move to the latest methods of writing, Also if you still want to use old techniques you can use a previous version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `React` and `ReactDOM` versions are not compatible with `react-bootstrap` versions, you need to update the respective packages to their latest versions since your ReactDOM is already at the latest

You can upgrade React to `15.5.4` too .

However you may face issues with the changes that have been made in the latest React versions, and I recommend you to folow the latest protocols since the support for the legacy one will be stopped in later releases.

However if you still want to use the old ways, you can upgrade react and react-dom to using `v15.1.0` for example

Comment: It is accepted now, I am very new to using SO (I always just read answers, first time asker). Also new to React so all the proper versions are bit unclear still.

Comment: Its alright @MirkoFlyktman, Also, I assume that the errors that you were getting because of latest version, are fixed

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

Better use this library, this is a very nice library as i had personally used this and works fine.
If it works for you don't forget to accept and upvote

Comment: His issue was not with modal but with version incomaptibility

Comment: okay bro, i just told about an alternative if that doesn't works for him